# Получение текста из запроса http

Tags: c++, visual-c++, post

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream request_stream("localhost", "http");
request_stream << "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: " << s.length() << "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" << s;
std::cout << request_stream.rdbuf();
```

Мой код

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: Cowboy

Connection: close

Date: Sat, 22 May 2021 11:49:54 GMT

Content-Length: 12

Via: 1.1 vegur

Success

Я получаю такой ответ от моего сервера. Как я могу вытащить только полученный текст, то есть success

Comment: Заголовки отделяются от тела двумя переводами строки.

Answer (score 0):

Встречал такое решение:

```
std::vector<std::string> headers;
std::string header;
while (std::getline(request_stream, header) && header != "\r")
    headers.push_back(header);
out << request_stream.rdbuf();
```

Заодно и заголовки собраны.